# Some events not working on FF?

Tags: javascript, firefox, onkeyup

When my webpage is loading, I use javascript to detect which browser is visiting the website and adjust the text size onload. This works all of the time on Firefox without any problems.

However, on the page I have two text inputs aligned ontop of each other (so the bottom one cannot be modified, to bypass the text dimming when the textbox is disabled). When the user types in the box, the idea is that there is an asterisk at the end of the text. My code for this is below. It is loaded onkeyup and onchange functions. This works perfectly in Chrome and Safari, but fails to work on Firefox.

Any ideas why?

```
function textcopy(form) {
    var text = consoleText.value;
    consoleText2.value = text + "*";
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that consoleText.value is null or undefined?

Comment: Nope. Having this problem when calling different functions from different events, too. I just figured if I solved this one, it would solve them all.

Comment: I doubt it is a firefox specific problem of onkeyup or onchange not working. There is likely something that you are doing that violates form but is not picked up by less strict browsers. Post your code so that we can help.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/azemor/edit#javascript,html,live - There you go.

Comment: Works when you're viewing that screen and write on the right, but now when you're on this page http://jsbin.com/azemor

Comment: `consoleText is not defined` is the error you get on http://jsbin.com/azemor

Comment: How would I go about fixing it?

Comment: possibly use `var consoleText = document.getElementById('consoleText')` instead of hoping the browser would map undefined variables to a DOMElement via its ID. Very bad practice…

Comment: Just figured that out myself as you were posting it. Thank you for the help, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `consoleText2.value = text+"*";` with `document.getElementById("consoleText").value = text+"*";`